# How to get data from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

```html
    Table1
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Rate</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Tomato</td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Brinjal</td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Potato</td>
    <td>30</td>
    </tr> 
    </table></br></br>
    Table2
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>New_rates</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>45</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>30</td>
    </tr>   

    </table>
    </br></br>
    I want my result to look like this

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Rate</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Tomato</td>
    <td>45</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Brinjal</td>
    <td>30</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Potato</td>
    <td>30</td>
    </tr> 
    </table>
```

table 1

```
Id   Name      rate
1   Tomato      10
2   Brinjal     10
3   Cucumber    30
```

table 2

```
Id  New_rate
1   25
```

I want my result to be like this

```
id   Name     rate
1   Tomato     25
2   Brinjal    10
3   Cucumber   30
```

Comment: Welcome - please read how to ask - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Research - There are lots of SQL examples already on this site to learn from if you want to join two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select table1.id, table1.name,
    IsNull(table2.new_rate, table1.rate) As rate
  From table1 
  Left Join table2 On table1.id = table2.id;
```

You need to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the second table because the second table doesn't have matching rows for all the rows in the first table.

Then you can use `IsNull()` function to show a value from table 2, or if one doesn't exist then show it from table 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select tb1.id,tb1.Name,tb2.New_rate from table_1 as tb1
join table_2 as tb2 on tb1.id=tb2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to update table1 with new values

```
update table1 set table1.rate=IsNull(table2.new_rate,table1.rate)
```

From table1 Left Join table2 On table1.id = table2.id;

then select table1 to view result

OR if you want to only select then try below:

```
   Select table1.id, table1.name,IsNull(table2.new_rate, table1.rate) As rate
   From table1 Left Join table2 On table1.id = table2.id;
```